# how to deal with -inf and Nan in numpy, when using log function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am sure many of you use numpy log function. How do you deal with Nan and -Inf? Is there any pythonic way to remove it from the array?

```
a = np.array([[0,1],
              [0,0],
              [1,1]])

b = np.log(a[:,0]/a[:,1])

print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply index the array where the values are finite using `np.isfinite()` (docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html)).

```py
>>> a = np.array([[0,1],
                  [0,0],
                  [1,1]])
>>> b = np.log(a[:,0]/a[:,1])
>>> b[np.isfinite(b)]
array([ 0.])
```

The `np.isfinite()` function will give you a boolean array the same size as the input array that is `True` wherever the value is finite, i.e. non-NaN and non-inf, and `False` otherwise:

```py
>>> np.isfinite(b)
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

which then can be used as a boolean index, so it will only grab the values out of `b` where this result is `True` (in this case, it's the final index, which has a value of 0).